# How to count total number of words without using string?

Tags: c, word-count

I implemented this code for getting no. of words count.  It works fine for all the single characters, i.e. if I type `"q     w    r   "` as input, it gives me 3 words, but when I type  `"qwe      ed     df   "` as input, it displays 2.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c=getchar();

    int words=0;

    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==' ' || c=='\n')
        {
            c=getchar();
        }
        else if(c>='a' && c<='z')
        {  
            c=getchar();

            if(c==' ')
            {
                words=words+1;
                c=getchar();
            }
            else
            {
               c=getchar();
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%i\n",words);
}
```

Comment: The normal technique is to use `while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)` — you get credit for using `int c;` and not `char c;`, incidentally — and then in the loop keep track of 'am I in a word'.  If you're in a word and you read a non-space, you're still in a word.  If you're in a word and you read a space, you've finished a word (and are no longer in a word).  If you're not in a word and you get a non-space character, you're now in a word; increment the word counter.  If you're not in a word and you get a space, you're still not in a word.  The `<ctype.h>` header has character classification macros.

Comment: read is in one place Or  look-ahead and `ungetc`.

Comment: If the files are large, consider buffering your reads (e.g. `char buf[1024] = ""; while (fgets (buf, 1024, stdin)) { char *p = buf; [your logic here]}`). The reason being, operations in memory are *orders of magnitude* faster than file I/O one-char at a time. (you can choose your `buf` size to be whatever makes sense. you will see significant improvement with buffers as small as 8 char)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is to count the boundaries.

Your original code has a bug around ...

```
        if(c==' ')
        {
            words=words+1;
            c=getchar();
        }
```

The code only counts words if a pair of reads results in `'a'` => `'z'` followed by `' '`.

The trick is to simplify the loop into a read one character at a time loop. (This ensure strange boundaries don't occur), and a state machine which models whether you are eating words, or spaces.

```
enum Mode { word = 1, spaces = 2 };
int c=getchar();
enum Mode currentMode = spaces;
int words=0;

while(c!=EOF)
{
    if(c==' ' || c=='\n')
    {
        if( currentMode == word ) {
            words=words+1;
        }
        currentMode = spaces;
    }
    else if(c>='a' && c<='z')
    {  
        currentMode = word;
    }
c=getchar();
}
// count the last word...
if( currentMode == word ) {
    words=words+1;
}
```

The code would now ignore any non-alpha character, as neither a word, nor a space.

EDIT : Fixed incorrect enum usage

Comment: I think you are assigning the mode state incorrectly? (spaces and words are switched)

Comment: Thanks @Daniel-Jour - fixed

Comment: 'Tis interesting — you're detecting the ends of words.  If you detected the start of words, you could avoid the increment after the loop.  You'd simply remove the condition in the 'if it is a space block' and its increment, and increment when you start a word (in the 'else if' block).  I think that would produce the same answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is your scattered calls to `getchar` which are hiding the bug which you are seeing.

You need something that checks if every character is a space and if every character is a letter.

Something like:

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
     if (c == ' ' || c == '\n') {

     } else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')

     } else {

    }
}
```

Now you just need to work out the logic inside those groupings.  You have the logic right (if the previous letter was a character and you get a space then increment the word, otherwise just keep going). But your multiple calls to `getchar` means you can *miss* that condition.

Fill in the gaps in the above and it should work. (And then test with upper case letters!).

Comment: again in the else if statement i have to call getchar() function to see if space is entered after a letter or not ....then what difference it would make to the previous code ?

Comment: @himanshujhamb: No don't do that, that's where your problems come from.  You can keep track of the previous letter, or have a flag which marks whether you were previously in a word.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the characters at too many places in your while loop. This is the reason getting wrong output.  Try to use this loop :

```
while(c!=EOF)
{
    while(c == ' ' || c == '\n') //consume multiple spaces
    {
        c = getchar();
    }

    for( int i=0 ;c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'; i++) //consuming a word
    {
        if(i == 0) //increment word count once at the start of each word
        {
            words++;
        }

        c = getchar();
    }

}
```

Comment: yup, 
You might have people with a complaint.
but 
I think  this cord  operate in a realistic range.

Answer (score 0):

your code have a problem with strings that have

> Even number of characters I think

the logic of the program isn't totally fine you have to add this condition inside the last `else` :

```
 if(c==' ')
   {
     words=words+1;
     c=getchar();
   }
```

the program will be like this:

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   int c=getchar();

    int words=0;

    while(c!=EOF)
    {
        if(c==' ' || c=='\n')
        {
            c=getchar();
        }
        else if(c>='a' && c<='z')
        {  
            c=getchar();
            if(c==' ')
            {
                words=words+1;
                c=getchar();
            }
            else
            {
               c=getchar();
               if(c==' ')
                {
                words=words+1;
                c=getchar();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",words);
    return 0;
}
```

because when you enter string of two characters and add a space, this last space will be read by the last `getchar` inside the `else` statement which don't increment the number of words.

check [this results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1aMp.png).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Did you saw the results included above?, here they are again [Results](http://i.stack.imgur.com/O1aMp.png).....

Answer (score 0):

Every time a letter follows a space (white-space) or is the first letter, increment your word count.  No need to limit count using narrow integers, file can be very long.

```
// Useful is...() functions declared here.
#include <ctype.h>

unsigned long long words = 0;
int previous = ' ';
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
  if (isspace(previous) && isalpha(ch)) words++;
  previous = ch;
}
 printf("%llu\n",words);
```

OP may want to adjust code to cope with digits, punctuation, etc.